# Add plain html Podcast-Link (no xml / rss) to gpodder

Tags: podcast, gpodder

One of my subscribed podcasts has recently changed it's podcast feed to rss 2.0 or so I believe to have read. At any rate other podcast sites seem to have no problem retrieving the mp3 files, whereas gpodder fails to download podcast files and subsequently failed to re-add that podcast after I removed it.

The feed is:

http://www.tagesschau.de/export/podcast/tagesthemen/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that gpodder has issues with some language encodings. It cannot create valid folder name for some feeds, so files cannot be downloaded to a non-existent folder.

It appears that gPodder stores podcast-feeds info in a file named ~/gpodder/Database

You can edit this file and make needed corrections for failed transfers with [DB Browser for SQL Lite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) For Ubuntu you can download the [source](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/archive/v3.9.1.tar.gz))

For Ubuntu if you want the latest version you'll need to compile it following the instructions included in the BUILDING.md file in the archive. This is fairly straightforward and instructions are reproduced and clarified here.

1) Make sure the `build-essential`, `cmake`, `libqt4-dev` and `libsqlite3-dev`
       packages are installed with the command `sudo apt-get install build-essential&&apt-get install&&apt-get install cmake&&apt-get install libqt4-dev&&apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`

2) Download the DB Browser for SQLite [source code](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/archive/v3.9.1.tar.gz))

3) Extract the tarball to the directory of your choice

4) Open a terminal in the source code directory `WhereYouExtracted/sqlitebrowser-3.9.1/src/`

5) Execute the following commands:

```
$ bash
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

This process should complete without errors, resulting in  a binary file called 'sqlitebrowser'

Alternatively there is also a PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~linuxgndu/+archive/ubuntu/sqlitebrowser) with recent versions available for Trusty through Yakkety.

Sources:

https://superuser.com/questions/540511/gpodder-cannot-download-podcasts-for-some-feeds

https://bugs.gpodder.org

http://sqlitebrowser.org/

https://launchpad.net/~linuxgndu/+archive/ubuntu/sqlitebrowser

https://github.com/gpodder/gpodder/issues

Comment: I installed the latest stable DB Browser for SQLite via the ppa's as you alternatively suggested and opened the gpodder/Database file. Now I don't know what to do...

This might just be down to me not really understanding the problem, but to me it seems like the publishers just changed the feed syntax in a way, that gpodder doesn't recognize, so I'd have to alter that. E.g. Chrome usually displays xml/rss feeds in paragraphs and indentations, but shows the tagesthemen feed as a plain html contiunous text.

Or should I manually add that feed via DB Browser for SQLite? Thanks anyway!!!

Comment: Same question regarding the new york times daily podcast:

https://art19.com/shows/the-daily

Comment: I wish I had more to add for you. You might find this related post useful.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/219542/how-to-add-authenticated-podcast-feed-to-rhythmbox?rq=1 It also appears that you may be able to get help from the developers (who know far more about this than I do [here](http://gpodder.org/)